# correlation coefficient between nominal categorical variables and discrete variables in R

Tags: r, correlation

How is it possible to calculate correlation coefficient(Effect size) between nominal categorical variables and discrete variables in R?

for each variables I have at least 10 values

Comment: How many levels for the categorical variable?

Comment: I have several categorical variable, one of them has  4 levels, another has 67 and others between these numbers.